# Is there a "cleaner" way to find the first instance of a derived class in a vector of pointers to base?

Tags: c++, templates, radix, derived

In my game engine, I am currently attempting to simplify the code:

```
std::vector<Base*> bases; //An arbitrary vector of the abstract class Base.

/*
GetFromBase
param derivedType: An integer used for quick comparison between each derived.
return: A pointer to the first derived found, or nullptr if not found.
*/

template <typename T>
T* GetFromBase(int derivedType)
{
  //Walk through each base
  for (Base* b : bases)
  {
    //Check if its internal type is the same as the enum
    if(b->GetDerivedType() == derivedType)
    {
      //Return the casted pointer
      return reinterpret_cast<T*>(b);
    }
  }

  //No derived of the desired type was found.
  return nullptr;
}
```

Is it possible to perform the same function with only the template parameter, and if so, is there a large performance hit?

Comment: Are you really sure you need to find the derived type? I have never found myself in that position. Also, there are many posts on this in stackoverflow.

Comment: It would be better to design your base and derived classes to be properly polymorphic, so down-casting is not necessary to use them.

Comment: If you really need `Derived *`s, why not hold onto them as well as the `Base *`s?

Comment: The reason I need derived types is because specific functionality is sometimes required. Specifically, my team is using a component architecture. Components are all updated using virtual functions and the like. However, if I needed to move a gameobject or change its sprite, that would require getting the transform/sprite derived component class. This is a common occurrence and I wanted to make typing faster.

Comment: @KeeganWesleyTompkins This seems not right. If you already have a typed component and call `GetTransform` or whatever, it should just do the right thing regardless. The only reason to use a reflection model like this is for exposing `class`es to scripting languages.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach has undefined behavior when the returned pointer is used, because `reinterpret_cast` is not able to cast pointers in the inheritance hierarchy generally. It will do the correct thing only if the derived object is [*pointer-interconvertible*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast#pointer-interconvertible) with the base class object. This is in particular only the case for [*standard-layout*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType) classes and classes with virtual functions are never standard-layout. `reinterpret_cast` does not change the address of the pointer, it just *reinterprets* it.

What you probably meant to use is `static_cast`, which *does* cast in the class hierarchy, by adjusting the pointer as necessary, assuming the pointed-to object is actually of derived type (which you verified with the test).

Alternatively you can get the same effect using `dynamic_cast`, which in contrast to `static_cast` does verify the derived type by itself and returns a null pointer if the object is not of the derived type:

```
auto d = dynamic_cast<T*>(b);
if(d)
    return d;
```

In contrast to your shown approach, `dynamic_cast` does not require the *most-derived* type to be equal to `T`, just that there is a (unique, `public`) `T` in the most-derived object's inheritance hierarchy.

In general you should avoid constructs like this. The need to know the derived type of an object is usually an indication that you didn't design the virtual interface correctly. All users of the base class pointer should only call functions in this interface and not care about the derived type.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative is to use `dynamic_cast`

```
template <typename T>
T* GetFromBase(std::vector<Base *> &bases)
{
  for (auto b : bases)
  {
    // try to cast
    if(auto ptr = dynamic_cast<T *>(b); ptr)  // <- c++17 syntax
    {
      return ptr;
    }
  }

  return nullptr;
}
```

Also shorter version using [std::find_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/)

```
template <typename T>
T* GetFromBase(std::vector<Base *> &bases)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(begin(bases), end(bases), [](Base *b) {
         return dynamic_cast<T *>(b);
    });
    return it == end(bases) ? nullptr : dynamic_cast<T *>(it);
}
```

Comment: Should mention that yes there is big performance hit. Most game engines disable `dynamic_cast` for runtime compilation.

Comment: @George You are right! But then the author's approach seems the right way to go.

Comment: Weren't you going for `if(auto ptr = dynamic_cast<T *>(b); ptr)` ?

Comment: `if(T* ptr = dynamic_cast<T *>(b))` isn't new in C++17, it's as old as C++

Comment: @Caleth And can you then use `return ptr` inside the if statement body in c++11?

Comment: Yes. It would be pointless to have a declaration if you couldn't use the name it declared

Comment: @Caleth edited example, forget to add a check for `ptr`

Comment: *That's* the "new in C++ 17" syntax. What you had before was fine

Comment: Notice that you cannot differentiate with `dynamic_cast` if the "final" type is this one, just that if it inherits from (or is) that class.